# NaN in fortran programming language

Tags: fortran

i use visual studio 2019 and intel fortran compiler 2021. in Fortran programming language for example when a number divided by zero, i want to stop program and show an error.
how to do this?

Comment: Can you post what you have done till now ? @Mohammad Rez

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you look at the floating point properties for your project you will find the mathematical error handing options available.

[image: fpe]

Select /fpe:0 to produce exceptions instead of `NaN`